# ng-class directive to show invalid password confirmation

Tags: javascript, angularjs

a quick question I have two inputs on my form that look like this:

```
      <input
        ng-keyup="validPasswordCheck()"
        ng-class="{'ng-invalid':!validPassword}"
        type="password" id="password" 
        ng-model="registerCredentials.password" 
        placeholder="Password">
      <input 
        ng-keyup="validPasswordCheck()"
        ng-class="{'ng-invalid':!validPassword}"
        type="password" id="password" 
        ng-model="registerCredentials.repeatPassword" 
        placeholder="Repeat Password">
```

And I have a controller that looks like this:

$scope.registerCredentials = {
        username: '',
        password: '',
        repeatPassword: ''
    };

```
$scope.validPasswordCheck = function() {
    $scope.validPassword = registerCredentials.password === registerCredentials.repeatPassword;
}
```

I'm trying to make it so when the passwords dont match they both have the class ng-invalid, and when they do match they shouldn't have the class. I'm trying to refresh the check to see it it's valid on every keyup (ng-keyup directive). This doesn't seem to work at all it is always invalid.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing `$scope` in front of your model variables:

```
$scope.validPassword = $scope.registerCredentials.password === $scope.registerCredentials.repeatPassword;
```